Cannot get text from a gridView
In the below code, I want to get the displayed text of each grid item (an interest) and append it to a MutableList before converting the entire MutableList into an array called selectedInterestsArray for later use in an Intent. However, the array has no elements after debugging. The text is displayed in the Toast widget (i.e. "History selected") though, so the text exists.
package com.example.gotravel01

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.GridView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.viewModels

class InterestsScreen : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var interestsGrid: GridView
    lateinit var interestsList: List<gridViewItem>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_interests)
        //initialize viewModel
        //val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>()
        var selectedInterests : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        val selectedInterestsArray: Array<String>
        var city = getIntent().getStringExtra("City")
        // define interestsGrid and interestsList
        interestsGrid = findViewById(R.id.interests_grid)
        interestsList = ArrayList<gridViewItem>()

        //populate interestsList ArrayList
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("History", R.drawable.coliseum)
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("Tourist hotspot", R.drawable.eiffel_tower_color)
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("Nature", R.drawable.nature)
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("Food", R.drawable.stage)
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("Museums", R.drawable.stage)
        interestsList = interestsList + gridViewItem("Religious sites", R.drawable.stage)
        //initialize adapter, pass interest list and context
        val gridAdapter = GridAdapter(interestList = interestsList, this@InterestsScreen)

        interestsGrid.adapter = gridAdapter

        interestsGrid.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, interestsList[position].title + " selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            selectedInterests.add(interestsList[position].title)
        }

        selectedInterestsArray = selectedInterests.toTypedArray()
        val nextButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonInterests)

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
            val intent = Intent(this, FamiliarityScreen::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("City", city);
            intent.putExtra("Selected Interests", selectedInterestsArray);
            startActivity(intent)
        });
    }
}

How can I fix this? Thank you.

You add to the selectedInterests in the grid item click listener (asynch and after onCreate completes) but attempt to fetch the selectedInterests in onCreate which would be empty.  Move the selectedInterestsArray assignment to inside the nextButton onClickLstener.  This assumes the user first selects grid items then clicks "next".
